# Azure Synapse - Select Insert

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

This is my 1st time working with Azure synapse and It seems Select Insert is not working, is there any workaround for this one, where I will just use select statement and then dump it into a temporary table?

here are the error prompted

> The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode.

and this is my query

> Select  *
> Into #Temp1
> FROM [dbo].[TblSample]

This is the azure synapse we are currently using

> ondemand-sql.azuresynapse.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Synapse On-Demand, the use of Temporary Tables is [limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-temporary?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259#temporary-tables-in-serverless-sql-pool). In your case I am assuming that `dbo.TblSample` is an External Table which is possibly why you are facing this restriction.

Instead of using a Temp Table, can you either just `JOIN` the `TblSample` directly or use a `CTE` if you are `SELECT`ing specific rows and columns?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to query all the columns

Comment: Then make your CTE all the columns:     ```WITH CTE as (SELECT * FROM dbo.TblSample) SELECT * FROM dbo.anotherTable a JOIN CTE b ON b.col1 = a.colz```